# Pip with ffmpeg to youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, youtube, overlay

I would like to have a picture in picture in top left with two rtsp livestreams without sound.

192.168.1.31 can do 12fps

192.168.1.13 can do 30fps

Now I have this :

```
ffmpeg  -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp  \
        -i rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.31:554  \
        -i rtsp://admin:654321@192.168.1.13:554  \
        -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/5:ih/5 [pip]; [1][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -profile:v main \
        -b:v 1500k \
        -q:v 3 \
        -vcodec libx264 \
        -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXXX
```

The pip image is the same as the main image which is the first stream and at bottom right ! What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the problem... Here is the correct line

```
ffmpeg  -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp  \
        -i rtsp://admin:654321@192.168.1.13:554  \
        -i rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.31:554  \
        -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/5:ih/5 [pip]; [2][pip] overlay=0:0" -profile:v baseline \
        -b:v 1500k \
        -q:v 3 \
        -tune zerolatency \
        -vcodec libx264   -preset ultrafast\
        -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXX
```